# using RSS feeds to make a weather app

Tags: android, mobile, rss, weather

i'm kinda new when it comes to RSS feeds and coding in general so forgive me if this is really basic stuff. I was tasked to create a weather app via BBC's RSS feed of their weather. I've been looking up tutorials and other sources for advice, guidance and walkthroughs into creating this but so far its all been using a add-on for android studio where i want to avoid them.

Is there any tutorials or walkthroughs that can help me in this.

Thanks
MB

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this free course:

[Udacity Developing Android Apps](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853)

You will learn how to make a weather app and retrieve data from a rest api (JSON) but not from a RSS Feed. You could adapt it to RSS Feed

However, making a app without coding experience it's not basic stuff ;) At first you should learn java and android basics. You could take the free supporting courses from [Udacity Android Basics Nanodegree](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-nanodegree-by-google--nd803).

Comment: thanks for the advice, ill have a look into it. based off what your saying is that i have to code it using JSON then convert it to a RSS feed. Would that be a difficult thing to do?

Comment: No. You should replace the code that reads the JSON data. It should read the XML data from the RSS feed instead of JSON. You can have a look here for [how to parse xml data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).